# DLNA result in crash When accessing a property

Tags: c++, ios

```
CGUpnpAvRenderer* avRender = self.deviceSource[indexPath.row];

if (avRender.cObject != nil)
{

    if (avRender.friendlyName == nil)
    {
        cell.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = avRender.friendlyName;
        button.selected = avRender.isSelect;
        NSLog(@"cell.name=== %@", avRender.friendlyName);
    }
}
else
{
    cell.hidden = YES;
}
```

I am doing this DLNA projection, and sometimes I can not access the object's properties, resulting in a crash, the library from the CyberLink Library.Thanks for you giving me an solution.

Comment: Could you explain `nil` please?

Comment: the crash occur when I access the proprety（the friendlyName）